# Разбор строки в соответствии с определённым паттерном

Tags: c#, .net

По сути я имею ввиду "обратное действие" к методу `string.Format`:

```
string format = "Number: {0}\nString: {1}\nBoolean: {2}\n";
string str = string.Format(format, 11, "example string", true);
```

Хотелось бы иметь что то вроде:

```
object[] values;
string.Extract(str, format, out values); // values: 11, "example string", true
```

Comment: Похоже, вам нужны регулярные выражения.

Comment: @tym32167 Я думал об этом. Но регулярные выражения не позволяют проверить соответствие строк. То есть нужен поиск не по определённому шаблону, а вытаскивание значений, расположенных в заданных местах строки.

Comment: Я отдельные слова в вашем комментарии понимаю, но мысль не улавливаю. Что такое соответствие строк? Что значит не по шаблону, если вы формат сами привели? Если вопрос про получение конкретной подстроки - используйте substring, или перефразируйте вопрос.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Под эту задачу хорошо подходят регулярные выражения.

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string[] Extract(this string text, string format)
    {
        string pattern = Regex.Replace(format, @"{\d+}", "(.+)");
        return Regex.Match(text, pattern).Groups.Cast<Group>().Skip(1).Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Проверям

```
string text = "Number: 11\nString: example string\nBoolean: true\n";
string format = "Number: {0}\nString: {1}\nBoolean: {2}\n";
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, text.Extract(format)));
```

Вывод в консоль

```
11
example string
true
```

Само собой это решение не на все случаи жизни, но его можно развивать. Я остановился на возврате массива строк. При необходимости каждое значение можно распарсить в нужный формат.